# Unique simple type element in parent complex type element

Tags: xml, unique

I wish to add unique constraint to the Name element of a `FamilyConvention` complex type. For some reason, the schema below does not detect duplicated names:

```
<xs:element name="ValidatedConvention">
   <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Family" type="FamilyConvention" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="KeyFamilyName">            
        <xs:selector xpath="Family/Name"/>          
        <xs:field xpath="."/>
    </xs:unique>
</xs:element>
<xs:complexType name="FamilyConvention">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Name" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:pattern value="([a-zA-Z0-9])+" />
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Compare to this XML:

```
<ValidatedConvention">
    <Family>
        <Name>john</Name>
    </Family>           
    <Family>
        <Name>john</Name>
    </Family>
</ValidatedConvention >
```

Do you see what's the problem with my schema?

Comment: Perhaps you've simplified the problem for us by removing namespace details? And perhaps it's namespaces that were the problem? People often forget that if the data is in a namespace, the names appearing in the xpath attribute of constraints like xs:unique have to be prefixed.

Answer (score 0):

**It seems to work**

Using http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/

I got:

***Not valid.
Error - Line 9, 26: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 26; Duplicate unique value [john] declared for identity constraint of element "ValidatedConvention".***

Which seems to be the result you were hoping for

To be able to test your xml I had to add a target namespace and xml version
Thats the code I used:

**XML**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<ValidatedConvention xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Family>
        <Name>john</Name>
    </Family>           
    <Family>
        <Name>john</Name>
    </Family>
</ValidatedConvention >
```

**XSD**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="ValidatedConvention">
   <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Family" type="FamilyConvention" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:unique name="KeyFamilyName">            
        <xs:selector xpath="Family/Name"/>          
        <xs:field xpath="."/>
    </xs:unique>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="FamilyConvention">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Name" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:pattern value="([a-zA-Z0-9])+" />
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

BTW: You have a single " at the end of your root element: ValidatedConvention

Update:

Yes, the namespace is causing the problem. See the comment under your initial question.

Have a look at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757863(v=vs.85).aspx on how to reference the schema

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers!

My original namespace details were:

XML:

```
<ValidatedConvention xmlns="dnx_ns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="dnx_ns file:///C:/Users/summer/workspace/project1/NewXMLSchema.xsd ">
```

schema:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="dnx_ns" xmlns="dnx_ns" elementFormDefault="qualified">
```

Were they wrong? How can I referred my XML to my schema without them?